# Buttons not working after cloning

Tags: jquery, button, clone

I'm cloning a list item into another list. However, none of the clone's buttons work in the new list. I'm stumped. Any ideas?

**JSfiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ornt4n3h/1/)**

Script:

```
    $(this).find(".add-playlist").on('click', function (ev) {
        var $clone = $(this).parent().parent().parent().clone(true);
        var $newbuttons = '<button class="btn btn-default clone" role="button">Clone</button><button class="btn btn-default delete" role="button">Delete</button>';
        ev.preventDefault();
        $clone.find('.tn-overlay').css({'top': '100%'}).end().find('.tn-buttons').html($newbuttons).end().appendTo($('#pl #da-thumbs')).hoverdir();
     });

$('.delete').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: when you start chaining `parent().parent().parent()`   use `closest('li.tn')` instead....a lot easier to read and therefore maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in order to attach an event to a dynamically inserted element.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/964fqtxq/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
});
```

As a side note, you should be using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) rather than chaining multiple `.parent()` methods.

Something like this would work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
    $(this).closest('.tn').remove();
});
```